# MySQL TIMEDIFF Less than an hour, invalid time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a function in MySQL that will select the time someone clocked in, and select the time someone clocked out and link them together. It will calculate how many hours that person has been on the clock in total between two provided dates. I then created another function that selects the break events and subtracts the break time from the total hours worked. It works great on any break times that are greater than an hour, anything less than that and it returns invalid data.

```
SELECT A1.volunteer_id, A1.datetime AS check_in_at, A2.datetime AS check_out_at,
       TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(A2.datetime, A1.datetime), '%h.%i') AS total_time
FROM volunteer_timeclock AS A1 INNER JOIN 
     volunteer_timeclock AS A2
     ON A1.volunteer_id = A2.volunteer_id AND 
        DATE(A1.datetime) = DATE(A2.datetime)
WHERE A1.status = 'break_start' AND
      A2.status = 'break_end' AND 
      DATE(A1.datetime) BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' AND
      DATE(A2.datetime) BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
ORDER BY A1.datetime DESC
```

This query will grab all of the break time between the beginning and the end of the year. The record I have in the database is 8:00AM to 9:15AM was a 15 minute break, and this will return 12.15 instead of 0.15.

Here is the data I currently have created inside of the database:

[image: Database View]

Here is the data I get back from my queries:

[image]

As you can see the yearly calculation is off because it is subtracting the break time of 12.15

Thank you!

Comment: Can we see the query to get the _"Volunteer Hours Weekly/Monthly/Yearly"_ ?

Comment: What is the data type of datetime?

Comment: The query is the same, I just give longer date ranges.

Comment: Data type for datetime is MySQL DATETIME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In summary

Try using `%H` instead of `%h` - it probably does something closer to what you're expecting.

### The long version

Look closely at the documentation for [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and [`TIME_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format).

For `DATE_FORMAT`, the specifier `%h` formats as: Hour (`01..12`). It also notes:

> The specifiers apply to other functions as well: `STR_TO_DATE(), TIME_FORMAT(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

For `TIME_FORMAT`:

> `TIME_FORMAT(time,format)`
>
> This is used like the `DATE_FORMAT()` function, but the *`format`*
>   string may contain format specifiers only for hours, minutes, seconds,
>   and microseconds. Other specifiers produce a `NULL` value or `0`.
>
> If the *`time`* value contains an hour part that is greater than 23,
>   the `%H` and `%k` hour format specifiers produce a value larger than
>   the usual range of `0..23`. The other hour format specifiers produce
>   the hour value modulo 12.

So, since `00:15:00` has an hour value of zero - not greater than 23 - the modulo 12 exception does not apply; `TIME_FORMAT` behaves like `DATE_FORMAT`, and the hour `00` is formatted as `12`.

```
    TIME_FORMAT('00:15:00', '%H %k %h %I %l')
1   00 0 12 12 12
```

Comment: This did fix it, thank you very much for the detailed description as well.